# Can't get text to underline on hover?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have this code:

```
e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='';";
```

This should make it so that when I hover over a row, all text in it will be underlined. But it's not working. I've also tried this:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.textDecoration='underline'");
```

Which isn't working either.

EDIT: This code works. Is there an alternative to style.textDecoration similar to this I could use, that does NOT require css?

```
e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.fontWeight='bold';";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you css instead?

```
.table-hover tr td:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.table-hover tr td {
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

then apply that class to your table (I guess you are using GridView):

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="table-hover">
   .....
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I did try to use css like that, but I was having trouble getting it to work. I'll try your example & get back to you, though! (and yes, I am using GridView)

Comment: what do you have in your td element? it may has an overwrite style. if it is, try put  !important after underline: `text-decoration: underline !important;` (notice: this is not a good practice though)

Answer (score 0):

You could rather use this:

`e.Row.Attributes.Add("class", "cell-hoverunderline");`

And then add a CSS style as such:

```
.cell-hoverunderline:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```